# Picasso and image size

Tags: android, picasso

I've a ListView and inside of it, every row has a text and an image downloaded and displayed with Picasso.

The images I am using comes from Spotify API and it provides different sizes, for example:

```
"images": [
          {
            "height": 789,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/99afd5b3e7ce4b82fdc007dc5ed8dfe0806f6fe2",
            "width": 779
          },
          {
            "height": 648,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/68e20f364ba16a4386d8f55ca6bed5fb8da3136d",
            "width": 640
          },
          {
            "height": 203,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/8e68acfb185a7370a3c4efdbdd42b3e1a5c82ac8",
            "width": 200
          },
          {
            "height": 65,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/a86ea149077b22239f41e8b17f7261c475b084ee",
            "width": 64
          }
        ],
```

I can use any of those but so far, I've solved the problem using the one with higher width and height and let Picasso do the resize magic.

So, is the cost of Picasso's resizing significant enough to care about it or shall I check the resolution/screen the current device has and download the appropriate image ? and if this is the case, how do I know which image i have to download ?

There's an obvious difference on network consumption but I am specifically curious about the resizing part.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * this method will apply the transformation and will automatically resize the images as per screen
 * 
 * @param lessWidth
 *             the value with which the width must be decreased for the image resize with respect to screen width
 */
public void apply(final int lessWidth)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Transformation transformation = new Transformation()
    {

        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source)
        {
            sourceBitmap = source;
            int targetWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - lessWidth;
            if (source.getWidth() > targetWidth)
            {
                double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
                int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
                Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
                if (result != source)
                {
                    source.recycle();
                }
                return result;
            }
            return source;
        }

        @Override
        public String key()
        {
            return "transformation" + " desiredWidth";
        }
    };
    if (strImageUrl == null || strImageUrl == "")
    {
        return;
    }

    Picasso.with(context).load(strImageUrl).transform(transformation).into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback()
    {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess()
        {
            MyLog.d("PicassoHelper", "ImageLoadSuccess: url=" + strImageUrl);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError()
        {
            MyLog.d("PicassoHelper", "ImageLoadError: url=" + strImageUrl);
            if (imageView != null && defaultBitmap != null)
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(defaultBitmap);
            }

        }
    });
}
```